# What is a good synonym for "settled"?

Tags: synonyms

The context I am thinking about is a sport competition or league, along the lines of

- GM's Tennis Competition (settled)
- Premier league will be (settled) this weekend
- The football game was (settled) last week

"Settled" sounds a bit like some legal dispute that is over.

Any ideas of good synonyms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree 'settled' sounds a bit legal, but you can say it. I think it just needs the verb 'debate' or noun 'question' in the sentence.

Examples: Debate-*The answer to the top German team debate will be settled on Saturday night between Munich and Dortmund.*

Question- *The question of which team is the best in Germany will be settled Saturday night at the end of the Pokal game.*

If you are looking for the winner or the outcome, I would say 'decided'.

- Premier league *winner or outcome* will be decided this weeekend *when team A defeats team B*.

Otherwise I would just say 'finished' 
 - The GM's Tennis Competition is finished.

Or

- The football game was played.

A short Google search (on google.ca) gets more hits back for the phrase 'the game was played' and 'the game was finished' than 'the game was settled'.

'The game was decided' comes back with more hits than 'settled', but less than 'finished'.

Answer (score 6):

**Decided** is the word that comes to my mind especially in this context